# Insert string at specific column - Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to be able to insert strings to align with specific spacing requirements;

```
Column1     Column2     Column3                        Column4  etc...
Instert1    Insert2     Insert(randomCharacterCount)3  Insert4
```

(the column headers do not adjust)

Currently the template has to be spelled out for each entry uniquely so it fits within the column spacing, if you make a change, it requires several checks to make sure it aligns with the start points of the columns.

Is there a way to inject a string at a specific starting point, rather than manually adding spaces throughout each entry? In short, insert string at character point 30, then the next string at character point 52, etc.

Currently, I am using this (which works):

```
{{ entry.model }},{{ ' ' * ( 20 - entry.model | length ) }}{{ entry.cores }},{{ ' ' * ( 5 - entry.cores | length ) }}{{ entry.thrds }},{{ ' ' * ( 5 - entry.thrds | length ) }}
```

I gather the number at the starting point of the next column back to the first character of the last column. It then gathers the length of the string and removes that from the available spaces and then inserts the remaining spaces. But man... is it long and ugly!

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

It requires a bit of convolution due to `set` in jinja2 not allowing reassignment, but otherwise it seemed to do as expected:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    columns: 'Column1     Column2     Column3                        Column4  etc'
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fmt_str: >-
          {%- set results = [] -%}
          {%- set prev = {"p":0} -%}
          {%- for p, w in (c_pads | zip(c_widths) | reverse) -%}
          {%- set _ = results.append(":<" ~ (w + prev.p)) -%}
          {%- set _ = prev.update({"p": p}) -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {%- for f in results | reverse -%}
          {{- "{" ~ loop.index0 ~ f ~ "}" -}}
          {%- endfor -%}
      vars:
        c_pads: '{{ columns | regex_findall("( *)[^ ]+") | map("length") | list }}'
        c_widths: '{{ columns | regex_findall(" *([^ ]+)") | map("length") | list }}'
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ columns }}
          {{ fmt_str.format(*a_row) }}
      vars:
        a_row: ["alpha", "beta", "charlie", "delta", "xyz"]
```

produces:

```
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    Column1     Column2     Column3                        Column4  etc
    alpha       beta        charlie                        delta    xyz
```

which is what I think you're after

There are a lot of sharp edges about overflow conditions, but I bet some study of https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples will help